# format yyyyMMdd string on datagridview

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

I need to format one string that is provided by mysql select that contains 19950501. His format is **yyyyMMdd** inside of datagridview and i want to format to this -> **05/01/1995**

I tried with  `DataGridTurnos.Columns(3).Format = "dd-MM-yyyy"` but it keeps showing 19950501..

EDIT1: It is stored with VARCHAR(8) but I cant change the table, because I have not access to it, and I can only change  it on vbnet inside datagridview..

Comment: If you want dates to act like dates you need to save to a `Date` column. Then,  you can use the `DefaultCellStyle` to display any format you want.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Would be useful to show how you're loading this data back from MySql, as well as the schema for the table itself

Comment: Yes I know that, it is stored with varchar(8), but I cant change the format to save it on mysql, because I haven't access to it. I have to change this format inside datagridview

Comment: @derloopkat, I tried it before and nothing happened. I tried now again and its the same.

Comment: `DataGridTurnos.Columns(3).ValueType = GetType(DateTime)` then `DataGridTurnos.Columns(3).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd-MM-yyyy"`

Comment: You must get the string into a date before any NET date formatting will work.  Try chopping up the string to M D Y parts and using the MySQL date functions to convert it.  How you are loading the data and how it gets into the DGV would be nice to know also.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub FormatDateString()
        Dim s As String = "19950501"
        Dim strYear As String = s.Substring(0, 4)
        Dim strMonth As String = s.Substring(4, 2)
        Dim strDay As String = s.Substring(6, 2)
        s = $"{strMonth}/{strDay}/{strYear}"
        Debug.Print(s)
End Sub
```

You could change this sub to a function, passing in your string and returning the new string then loop through all your DataGridRows accessing the column that needs changing. Probably be quicker to go through the in memory DataTable used to fill the grid or whatever you are using to fill grid.